# Overiding same method in Super Class and Interface

Tags: java, inheritance

I am extending a Class as well as implementing an interface, both contain a method called `doFilter` , it is a final method in my super class and off course an abstract method from my interface . So, now I am getting compiler error.

How should i resolve this.

My filter class is :

```
public class MyCacheFilter extends CachingFilter implements Filter {
    // here is error, as compiler is thinking I am overriding dofilter of
    // CacheFilter, although I have not specified any @Override annotation

    public doFilter() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does CachingFilter implements Filter as well?

Comment: CacheFilter extends net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter
 which implements java.servlet.filter

Answer (score 3):

If the method is provided by `CachingFilter` you don't have to provide an implementation in `MyCacheFilter`. (In fact, as you've discovered, you *can't*.)

If you really want a different behavior of `doFilter` than what is provided by `CachingFilter` then inheritance is not an option. In that case, consider using composition:

```
public class MyCacheFilter implements Filter {

    CachingFilter cachingFilter = ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter() {
        ...
        possibly refer to cachingFilter...
        ...
    }

    public String otherMethod() {
        // delegate to cachingFilter
        return cachingFilter.otherMethod();
    }
}
```

> ***[...] although I have not specified any @Override annotation***

Whether or not you explicitly provided `@Override` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: great,I understood ,but why compiler is showing me "Can't override a final method from Filter" as It is not final there.Also I checked the javadoc of EHCache CachingFilter class, doFilter is also not marked final there.

Comment: If a method is `final` it can't be overriden. It doesn't matter if *you* don't write `final` in your subclass... it is whether or not the method is `final` in the super class that decides if you may override it in any sub class or not.

Comment: "In fact, as you've discovered, you can't" this is only true if the method in the superclass is declared `final`, which does not appear to be the case here. Might want to clear up that wording.

Comment: To quote the OP: *it is a final method in my super class*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the method is declared *final* in the superclass. That means, literally, "this method can't be overridden". If you need to put your own logic in `doFilter()`, you can't extend the CachingFilter.

There is no concept in Java of *where* you override a method from. The interface is the contract which tells others what your class can do. The complete contract is the sum of all interfaces implemented. It doesn't matter if an identical method signature is present in more than one interface. The class is the implementation of the contract.

Inheritance starts from the top (ie Object) and each overridden method replaces any pre-existing definitions from any parent as the publicly exposed method - **except** if a method is declared `final`. That tells the compiler that this method implementation is not allowed to be overridden, this is the *final* version of it.

EDIT: I don't know what the `CachingFilter` you are using is coming from, but a common pattern in frameworks layered on top of other frameworks or java standard API is to create a final implementation of the API-required method (`doFilter()` in this case), but add another "internal" method (like `internalDoFilter()`) that gets called from the `doFilter()`. Extending classes can then safely override the "internal" method while still guaranteeing that any essential logic in `doFilter()` is still executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to resolve such conflicts directly, other than by rethinking your class design. You could

- rename the method in the interface, or
- change `MyCacheFilter` to *contain* a `CachingFilter` rather than inherit from it, or
- **if** the superclass implementation suits your needs, you can (as @aioobe mentioned) leave the method out of your subclass altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If CachingFilter.dofilter() is available, it will be a method in your child class. So you don't need to override it. If you want to override, method shouldn't be final.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the interface as anonymous.

```
public class MyClass extends MySuperClass implements MyInterface{

MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface(){

/* Overrided method from interface */
@override
public void method1(){

}

};

/* Overrided method from superclass*/
@override
public void method1(){

}

}
```